# USB device not appearing under macOS, not even in USB Prober

Tags: macos, serial-port, usb, iokit, pyusb

I am trying to get a simple USB device to work on macOS. The device works on Windows, through the use of `usbser.sys` driver: a simple .inf file is provided and that seems to do the trick (with a .cat file). My reading of `usbser.sys` is that it will take ownership of USB Communication Device Class (CDC) devices.

I have written user-space drivers for many different devices before by deconstructing USB devices on macOS.  My strategy has always been the same: use USB Prober.app (or more recently PyUSB) to get a listing of USB devices with all their configuration parameters, interfaces, pipes & endpoints. The information obtained is enough to fully grasped the device: I can see if the device can be serialized (i.e., to get /dev/cu.serialxxx through some driver) or not, I can see the USB configurations and the USB interfaces.  Of course, when possible (that is, when a USB kernel extension takes ownership of the device and serializes it), I use POSIX libraries the serialized version because it is simpler. However, when needed, I use IOKit to access the device directly and find (after trial and error) the right pipes/endpoints for communication.

But I am completely baffled: the device, when connected (it is a laser from Cobolt Lasers) does not show up at all, not even as a USB raw device although it works perfectly well (and every time) on a Windows 10 machine. It is a CDC device, as I validated on Windows.  It should be taken by at least the AppleUSBCDC.kext, but no: it does not show up in System Report, in USB Prober or PyUSB listing so of course it does not show up at all in /dev/.  I am quite puzzled because although I am no USB expert, I thought I understood that a USB device does not need to be taken by a driver to show up **at least** in System Report, which would be enough for me to write my own user-space driver using IOKit (which I have done for other devices in the past).

My questions:

1. Should I expect my device to show up at least in System Report without a driver? What is the solution if I am missing something?
2. Why isn't AppleUSBCDC.kext not taking the CDC device as a last resort?
3. Is there an equivalent to `usbser.sys` on macOS (Mojave) if it's not AppleUSBCDC.kext ?

EDIT 1:
Following the comments, I used `sudo dmesg` and saw errors during the enumeration process (see below).  My working hypothesis at this point is that the USB device descriptor is not quite valid, but that is not a problem on Windows although it is on macOS.

EDIT 2:
Ot appears to be an invalid USB device descriptor, although I am unable to find the exact error in the descriptor.  I posted another question regarding a USB device descriptor validator.

I am pasting here the USB information obtained by connecting the device to a Windows machine which to me, clearly indicates that AppleUSBCDC.kext should really take the device and serialize it because CDC devices are (always?) serializable:

```
    =========================== USB Port8 ===========================

Connection Status        : 0x01 (Device is connected)
Port Chain               : 3-8

      ======================== USB Device ========================

        +++++++++++++++++ Device Information ++++++++++++++++++
Friendly Name            : Cobolt Laser (COM7)
Device Description       : Cobolt Laser
Device Path              : \\?\usb#vid_25dc&pid_0006#000013245678#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}
Device ID                : USB\VID_25DC&PID_0006\000013245678
Hardware IDs             : USB\VID_25DC&PID_0006&REV_0100 USB\VID_25DC&PID_0006
Driver KeyName           : {4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0006 (GUID_DEVCLASS_PORTS)
Driver                   : system32\DRIVERS\usbser.sys (Version: 6.1.7601.18247  Date: 2013-08-28)
Driver Inf               : C:\Windows\inf\oem107.inf
Legacy BusType           : PNPBus
Class                    : Ports
Class GUID               : {4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318} (GUID_DEVCLASS_PORTS)
Interface GUID           : {a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed} (GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE)
Service                  : usbser
Enumerator               : USB
Location Info            : Port_#0008.Hub_#0001
Location IDs             : PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1400)#USBROOT(0)#USB(8)
Container ID             : {1ddbadd3-ec62-5d3a-a00a-64685c39b2e8}
Manufacturer Info        : Cobolt AB
Capabilities             : 0x94 (Removable, UniqueID, SurpriseRemovalOK)
Status                   : 0x0180600A (DN_DRIVER_LOADED, DN_STARTED, DN_DISABLEABLE, DN_REMOVABLE, DN_NT_ENUMERATOR, DN_NT_DRIVER)
Problem Code             : 0
Power State              : D0 (supported: D0, D3, wake from D0)
COM-Port                 : COM7 (\Device\USBSER000)

        +++++++++++++++++ Registry USB Flags +++++++++++++++++
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\UsbFlags\25DC00060100
 osvc                    : REG_BINARY 00 00
 SkipContainerIdQuery    : REG_BINARY 01 00 00 00

        ---------------- Connection Information ---------------
Connection Index         : 0x08 (8)
Connection Status        : 0x01 (DeviceConnected)
Current Config Value     : 0x01
Device Address           : 0x0B (11)
Is Hub                   : 0x00 (no)
Number Of Open Pipes     : 0x03 (3)
Device Bus Speed         : 0x01 (Full-Speed)
Pipe0ScheduleOffset      : 0x00 (0)
Pipe1ScheduleOffset      : 0x00 (0)
Pipe2ScheduleOffset      : 0x00 (0)
Data (HexDump)           : 08 00 00 00 12 01 00 02 02 00 00 08 DC 25 06 00   .............%..
                           00 01 01 02 03 01 01 01 00 0B 00 03 00 00 00 01   ................
                           00 00 00 07 05 82 03 40 00 08 00 00 00 00 07 05   .......@........
                           01 02 40 00 01 00 00 00 00 07 05 81 02 40 00 01   ..@..........@..
                           00 00 00 00                                       ....

    ---------------------- Device Descriptor ----------------------
bLength                  : 0x12 (18 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x01 (Device Descriptor)
bcdUSB                   : 0x200 (USB Version 2.00)
bDeviceClass             : 0x02 (Communications and CDC Control)
bDeviceSubClass          : 0x00
bDeviceProtocol          : 0x00 (No class specific protocol required)
bMaxPacketSize0          : 0x08 (8 bytes)
idVendor                 : 0x25DC
idProduct                : 0x0006
bcdDevice                : 0x0100
iManufacturer            : 0x01 (String Descriptor 1)
 Language 0x0409         : "Cobolt AB"
iProduct                 : 0x02 (String Descriptor 2)
 Language 0x0409         : "Cobolt Laser Driver MLD"
iSerialNumber            : 0x03 (String Descriptor 3)
 Language 0x0409         : "000013245678"
bNumConfigurations       : 0x01 (1 Configuration)
Data (HexDump)           : 12 01 00 02 02 00 00 08 DC 25 06 00 00 01 01 02   .........%......
                           03 01                                             ..

    ------------------ Configuration Descriptor -------------------
bLength                  : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x02 (Configuration Descriptor)
wTotalLength             : 0x0043 (67 bytes)
bNumInterfaces           : 0x02 (2 Interfaces)
bConfigurationValue      : 0x01 (Configuration 1)
iConfiguration           : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
bmAttributes             : 0x80
 D7: Reserved, set 1     : 0x01
 D6: Self Powered        : 0x00 (no)
 D5: Remote Wakeup       : 0x00 (no)
 D4..0: Reserved, set 0  : 0x00
MaxPower                 : 0x32 (100 mA)
Data (HexDump)           : 09 02 43 00 02 01 00 80 32 09 04 00 00 01 02 02   ..C.....2.......
                           01 00 05 24 00 10 01 05 24 01 01 01 04 24 02 06   ...$....$....$..
                           05 24 06 00 01 07 05 82 03 40 00 08 09 04 01 00   .$.......@......
                           02 0A 00 00 00 07 05 01 02 40 00 01 07 05 81 02   .........@......
                           40 00 01                                          @..

        ---------------- Interface Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x04 (Interface Descriptor)
bInterfaceNumber         : 0x00
bAlternateSetting        : 0x00
bNumEndpoints            : 0x01 (1 Endpoint)
bInterfaceClass          : 0x02 (Communications and CDC Control)
bInterfaceSubClass       : 0x02 (Abstract Control Model)
bInterfaceProtocol       : 0x01 (AT Commands defined by ITU-T V.250 etc)
iInterface               : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
Data (HexDump)           : 09 04 00 00 01 02 02 01 00                        .........

        -------------- CDC Interface Descriptor ---------------
bFunctionLength          : 0x05 (5 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x24 (Interface)
bDescriptorSubType       : 0x00 (Header Functional Descriptor)
bcdCDC                   : 0x110 (CDC Version 1.10)
Data (HexDump)           : 05 24 00 10 01                                    .$...

        -------------- CDC Interface Descriptor ---------------
bFunctionLength          : 0x05 (5 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x24 (Interface)
bDescriptorSubType       : 0x01 (Call Management Functional Descriptor)
bmCapabilities           : 0x01
 D7..2:                  : 0x00 (Reserved)
 D1   :                  : 0x00 (sends/receives call management information only over the Communication Class interface)
 D0   :                  : 0x01 (handles call management itself)
bDataInterface           : 0x01
Data (HexDump)           : 05 24 01 01 01                                    .$...

        -------------- CDC Interface Descriptor ---------------
bFunctionLength          : 0x04 (4 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x24 (Interface)
bDescriptorSubType       : 0x02 (Abstract Control Management Functional Descriptor)
bmCapabilities           : 0x06
 D7..4:                  : 0x00 (Reserved)
 D3   :                  : 0x00 (not supports the notification Network_Connection)
 D2   :                  : 0x01 (supports the request Send_Break)
 D1   :                  : 0x01 (supports the request combination of Set_Line_Coding, Set_Control_Line_State, Get_Line_Coding, and the notification Serial_State)
 D0   :                  : 0x00 (not supports the request combination of Set_Comm_Feature, Clear_Comm_Feature, and Get_Comm_Feature)
Data (HexDump)           : 04 24 02 06                                       .$..

        -------------- CDC Interface Descriptor ---------------
bFunctionLength          : 0x05 (5 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x24 (Interface)
bDescriptorSubType       : 0x06 (Union Functional Descriptor)
bControlInterface        : 0x00
bSubordinateInterface[0] : 0x01
Data (HexDump)           : 05 24 06 00 01                                    .$...

        ----------------- Endpoint Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x07 (7 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x05 (Endpoint Descriptor)
bEndpointAddress         : 0x82 (Direction=IN EndpointID=2)
bmAttributes             : 0x03 (TransferType=Interrupt)
wMaxPacketSize           : 0x0040 (64 bytes)
bInterval                : 0x08 (8 ms)
Data (HexDump)           : 07 05 82 03 40 00 08                              ....@..

        ---------------- Interface Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x04 (Interface Descriptor)
bInterfaceNumber         : 0x01
bAlternateSetting        : 0x00
bNumEndpoints            : 0x02 (2 Endpoints)
bInterfaceClass          : 0x0A (CDC-Data)
bInterfaceSubClass       : 0x00
bInterfaceProtocol       : 0x00
iInterface               : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
Data (HexDump)           : 09 04 01 00 02 0A 00 00 00                        .........

        ----------------- Endpoint Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x07 (7 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x05 (Endpoint Descriptor)
bEndpointAddress         : 0x01 (Direction=OUT EndpointID=1)
bmAttributes             : 0x02 (TransferType=Bulk)
wMaxPacketSize           : 0x0040 (64 bytes)
bInterval                : 0x01 (ignored)
Data (HexDump)           : 07 05 01 02 40 00 01                              ....@..

        ----------------- Endpoint Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x07 (7 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x05 (Endpoint Descriptor)
bEndpointAddress         : 0x81 (Direction=IN EndpointID=1)
bmAttributes             : 0x02 (TransferType=Bulk)
wMaxPacketSize           : 0x0040 (64 bytes)
bInterval                : 0x01 (ignored)
Data (HexDump)           : 07 05 81 02 40 00 01                              ....@..

    ----------------- Device Qualifier Descriptor -----------------
Error                    : ERROR_GEN_FAILURE

      -------------------- String Descriptors -------------------
             ------ String Descriptor 0 ------
bLength                  : 0x04 (4 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x03 (String Descriptor)
Language ID[0]           : 0x0409 (English - United States)
Data (HexDump)           : 04 03 09 04                                       ....
             ------ String Descriptor 1 ------
bLength                  : 0x14 (20 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x03 (String Descriptor)
Language 0x0409          : "Cobolt AB"
Data (HexDump)           : 14 03 43 00 6F 00 62 00 6F 00 6C 00 74 00 20 00   ..C.o.b.o.l.t. .
                           41 00 42 00                                       A.B.
             ------ String Descriptor 2 ------
bLength                  : 0x30 (48 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x03 (String Descriptor)
Language 0x0409          : "Cobolt Laser Driver MLD"
Data (HexDump)           : 30 03 43 00 6F 00 62 00 6F 00 6C 00 74 00 20 00   0.C.o.b.o.l.t. .
                           4C 00 61 00 73 00 65 00 72 00 20 00 44 00 72 00   L.a.s.e.r. .D.r.
                           69 00 76 00 65 00 72 00 20 00 4D 00 4C 00 44 00   i.v.e.r. .M.L.D.
             ------ String Descriptor 3 ------
bLength                  : 0x1A (26 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x03 (String Descriptor)
Language 0x0409          : "000013245678"
Data (HexDump)           : 1A 03 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 31 00 33 00 32 00   ..0.0.0.0.1.3.2.
                           34 00 35 00 36 00 37 00 38 00                     4.5.6.7.8.
             ----- String Descriptor 0xEE -----
bLength                  : 0x02 (2 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x03 (String Descriptor)
Language 0x0409          : ""  *!*CAUTION  zero length
Data (HexDump)           : 02 03                                             ..
```

Comment: It should normally show up in System Report, but the truly reliable way to see if it's in the system at all is by directly inspecting the IOKit registry. Can you find anything that looks like your device in the output of the command `ioreg -irc IOUSBDevice`? If not, I suspect a hardware problem, perhaps a power delivery issue? Also, don't knock it until you've tried it: does a cold system start (shutdown & power back on) help? USB ports will sometimes perform a safety shutdown and stop working until the system is powered off.

Comment: Other things to try in case it doesn't show in `ioreg`: try a different (shorter) cable; try behind a hub if previously directly attached to the Mac, or directly attach if previously behind a hub.

Comment: It really does not show up at all.  I have not investigated the cable, but I have three new cables I will test tomorrow.  Also, the idea of using a hub is a good idea: if it is a kernel extension issue, the hub chip would act as a middleman and would make macOS talk to the hub (say FTDI, which always works) and the hub chip would talk to the problematic device.  I will also try that tomorrow.

Comment: After you attach the device, run `sudo dmesg` and see if there's any errors/messages printed to the kernel log. Maybe the macOS USB stack really doesn't like something about the device descriptor, or there's something weird at a lower level

Comment: ah ah! That is useful: IOUSBHostDevice@14300000: IOUSBHostDevice::start: failed to get device descriptor 
and 
AppleUSBHostPort::disconnect: persistent enumeration failures

Comment: I edited my question to include this information: I am assuming the device descriptor is not quite valid and this is a problem on macOS, but not Windows.  I know of other cases (for instance, when the configuration number is labelled as '0', I understand this is not valid, but mac+windows used to accept it and modify it on the fly, although they don't anymore) so this is reasonable.

Comment: The only warning I can see (from the device descriptor dump I obtained in windows) is the last string:

Language 0x0409          : ""  *!*CAUTION  zero length
Not sure if it is valid to have a zero-length string.